# Count of posts within WP Loop not counting posts to use for div class

Tags: php, wordpress

I've successfully been able to count the number of posts within a loop before, but for some reason this time it won't work.

```
<?php $count = 0; if (have_posts () ) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); $count++; ?>
<div class="post-<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Anything Im missing?

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: Its not showing post-1, post-2, post-3....etc

Comment: and what it is showing? it's only a class of div, why would it show anything? at least tell what output are you getting

Comment: It just shows 'post-'
Im trying to classify the divs in the WP loop, so I can add another div below with a conditional. Make sense?

Comment: PHP code is fine, you got to have problem somewhere else

Comment: You know what it was? I had the <div> content in another template get_template_part(). Does the $count only work in the same php file? Because I moved the elements to the parent php file and it started counting

Comment: yes because `get_template_part()` is a function, where `$count` doesn't exist, you would have to add `global $count;` line to it

Comment: Good to know. Learn something new everyday. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
After talking to @FlashThunder about this problem. it seems that putting the beginning of the loop in the home.php template and using `get_template_part()` for the posts that are to be counted won't work unless they are in the same template, otherwise we would need to use `global $count`. After putting all of the php in the same template, the posts counted and applied the numeric class to the div's like I wanted.